# "Linked Server" com MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-select, sql-update

SGBD: SQL SERVER 2014 + MySQL 5.5

Quais são as sintaxes do SELECT, INSERT e UPDATE ao invés de usar a função "OPENQUERY", ao fazer a conexão através do Linked Server do SQL SERVER, conectando no MySQL?

Comment: OPENQUERY é melhor opção e com maior performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma forma, configure o *RPC Out* para `true` como na figura abaixo, nas propriedades do seu Linked Server, que no caso é *CONEXAOMYSQLODBC*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora faça assim:

*Obs: `generics` é o banco e `cidades` o nome da tabela*

*Select:*

```
Execute('SELECT * FROM `generics`.`cidades`') at CONEXAOMYSQLODBC
```

*Insert*

```
Execute('INSERT INTO `generics`.`cidades`(`ufid`,`cidade`) VALUES(1,"ROSANA")') at CONEXAOMYSQLODBC
```

*Update*

```
Execute('UPDATE `generics`.`cidades` SET `cidade`="Presidente Venceslau" WHERE `cidadeid`=10') at CONEXAOMYSQLODBC
```

*Delete*

```
Execute('DELETE FROM `generics`.`cidades` WHERE `cidadeid`=10') at CONEXAOMYSQLODBC
```

mas, lembrando que a melhor solução é com *OpenQuery*.

Comment: Obrigado! resolveu o problema!